# Why is $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ equal to $x$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> Why is $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ equal to $x$?

Most videos only state this but give no explanation other than: "They cancel." As these are not reciprocals, how do they "cancel"?

Comment: because this is the inverse function and we get $$f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$

Comment: You'd better say that "their effects cancel out" or compensate each other. $\arcsin(\sin x)=x$, so that the composition of the two functions is neutral (at least in some range). This is true for all inverse functions, both ways: $f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x$.

Answer (score 9):

By definition, $\arcsin\colon[-1,1]\longrightarrow\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ is the inverse of the restriction to $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ of the sine function. Therefore, for each $x\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ we have $\arcsin\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)=x$ because that's part of the definition of inverse functions. The other part of the definition says that, if $x\in[-1,1]$, then $\sin\bigl(\arcsin(x)\bigr)=x$.

Comment: good to point out it is only valid on these intervals.

Answer (score 6):

It is **not** valid for all $x$! E.g. $\arcsin(\sin(10 \tfrac{\pi}{4})) = \arcsin(1) =  \tfrac{\pi}{2}.$
Since $\sin(x)$ is periodic, you have to restrict $x$ to $[- \tfrac{\pi}{2}, \tfrac{\pi}{2}].$ For other $x$ you get a saw-tooth function for $\arcsin(\sin(x))$
[image]

Comment: Note that this is a triangle wave, at least in audio engineering. Sawtooth vs triangle and other forms can be seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave

Answer (score 1):

If $f:A \to B$ is a bijective map, then $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for all $x \in A$.

This is meant by "cancel".

Comment: i think cancel is the wrong for this, i would say sich gegenseitig aufheben, but i don't know what it is in english

Comment: But isn't this statement false for arcsin and sin? It's true only for x ∈ [−π/2,π/2].
Dr. G: I agree "cancel out" doesn't feel quite right, perhaps  "invert?" "Undoes?" But I used Google translate on your German and got "cancel each other out." :)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps seeing this graphically will help.

Restricting $x \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ in order that a unique value for $\arcsin(x)$ exists the black arrows on the plot below show the effect of $x\to \sin(x) = y$. The the red arrows then show the effect of $y \to \arcsin(y)=\arcsin(\sin(x)) = x$ and you end up back where you started.

You might imagine extending the graph beyond $x \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ to see why a unique value of $\arcsin(x)$ would not exist.

[image]